# Extract part of string that matches between two substrings

Tags: python, r, perl, pattern-matching, substring

I have three files containing a set of strings. File1 and File2 contain a substring of File3. I want to substract the string from File3 that lies between the substrings in File1 and File2. Please see my example below:

File1 (substring 1):

```
 head(fivep$V2)
[1] UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUACAGUU  UGAGGUAGUAGUUUGUGCUGUU  ACAUACUUCUUUAUAUGCCCAUA UAGCAGCACAUCAUGGUUUACA 
[5] GGGUUCCUGGCAUGCUGAUUU   AGAGCUUAGCUGAUUGGUGAAC
```

File2 (substring 2)

```
 head(threep$V2)
[1] ACUGUACAGGCCACUGCCUUGC CUGCGCAAGCUACUGCCUUGCU UGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAU CGAAUCAUUAUUUGCUGCUCUA
[5] AUCACAUUGCCAGGGAUUACC  UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCUGC
```

File3

```
head(hairpin$V2)
[1] UACACUGUGGAUCCGGUGAGGUAGUAGGUUGUAUAGUUUGGAAUAUUACCACCGGUGAACUAUGCAAUUUUCUACCUUACCGGAGACAGAACUCUUCGA
[2] AUGCUUCCGGCCUGUUCCCUGAGACCUCAAGUGUGAGUGUACUAUUGAUGCUUCACACCUGGGCUCUCCGGGUACCAGGACGGUUUGAGCAGAU     
[3] AAAGUGACCGUACCGAGCUGCAUACUUCCUUACAUGCCCAUACUAUAUCAUAAAUGGAUAUGGAAUGUAAAGAAGUAUGUAGAACGGGGUGGUAGU   
[4] UAAACAGUAUACAGAAAGCCAUCAAAGCGGUGGUUGAUGUGUUGCAAAUUAUGACUUUCAUAUCACAGCCAGCUUUGAUGUGCUGCCUGUUGCACUGU 
[5] CGGACAAUGCUCGAGAGGCAGUGUGGUUAGCUGGUUGCAUAUUUCCUUGACAACGGCUACCUUCACUGCCACCCCGAACAUGUCGUCCAUCUUUGAA  
[6] UCUCGGAUCAGAUCGAGCCAUUGCUGGUUUCUUCCACAGUGGUACUUUCCAUUAGAACUAUCACCGGGUGGAAACUAGCAGUGGCUCGAUCUUUUCC
```

Example:

```
                                 String in File1                       String in  File2
                              AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA                   UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC
String in File3      CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG
```

Output from this example:

```
GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG
```

Comment: what are the two substrings?

Comment: Place your code here and then we can have a look on that where exactly you are facing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `qdapRegex` in R:

```
f1 <- "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA"
f2 <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC"
f3 <- "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG"

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(f3, f1, f2, extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG"
```

As the name implies `rm_between` removes or grabs items between a left and right boundary.  Use `extract = TRUE` to grab the string between the boundaries.  The returned value is a list as there may be multiple extractions for each string.  If this is undesirable then use `unlist` as in `unlist(rm_between(f3, f1, f2, extract=TRUE))`.

Answer (score 4):

In Perl you can try this code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file1 = "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA";
my $file2 = "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC";
my $file3 = "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG";

my ($result) = $file3 =~ /$file1(.*?)$file2/;

print $result;
```

Outputs:

```
GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution in R:

```
file1 <- "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA"
file2 <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC"
file3 <- "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG"

# create a regular expression
pattern <- paste0(".*", file1, "(.*)", file2, ".*")

# extract the substring
sub(pattern, "\\1", file3)
# [1] "GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG"
```

Comment: @user3741035 Do you want to use all combinations of the strings in file 1 and file 2?

Answer (score 1):

In `python`

```
>>> a='AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA'
>>> b='UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC'
>>> c='CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG'
>>> regex = a + '(.*?)' + b
>>> regex
'AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA(.*?)UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC'
>>> re.findall(regex,c)
['GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with `strapplyc` in gsubfn.  We have assumed that there is only one instance of `s1` and `s2` or if there are multiple instances that you want the string between the first instance of `s1` and the last instance of `s2`.  If there can be multiple instances and you want something different add this to the question.

```
s1 <- "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA"
s2 <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC"
s3 <- "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG"

library(gsubfn)
fn$strapplyc(s3, "$s1(.*)$s2", simplify = TRUE)
##  [1] "GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG"
```

Comment: I have edited my question. I have multiple strings in file 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

In python
`

```
    string1 = "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA"
    string2 = "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC"
    string_main = "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG"
    print string_main[string_main.find(string1)+len(string1):string_main.find(string2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Based off your given input, the following would work.

```
f1 <- "AGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCA"
f2 <- "UUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGC"
f3 <- "CUGAGGAGCAGGGCUUAGCUGCUUGUGAGCAGGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUGUUCACAGUGGCUAAGUUCCGCCCCCCAG"
strsplit(f3, paste(f1, f2, sep='|'))[[1]][2]
# [1] "GGGUCCACACCAAGUCGUG"
```